# Is there a way in typescript to restrict a parameter to be one of the keys of an object and that key to have a certain type?

Tags: typescript

I want to know if it’s possible in typescript to have something like:

```
func<T,V>(prop: keyof T: V)

interface IIntf{
  prop1: string,
  prop2: number
}

func<IIntf, string>(‘prop1’) //OK
func<IIntf, string>(‘prop2’) //NOT OK (prop2 is of type number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using mapped types and type inference, like in the following type that will extract only keys with specified type:

```
type ObjectKeysWithType<T, V> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```

The reasoning here is:

1. Map the type (using Mapped types) to the values only if they match (`T[K] extends`) the desired type (`V`)
2. Extract the keys using `{ .. }[keyof T`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AaQiAzgdQJbAAWAKuBADzEA0UAagHxQC8UA3gFBRdQDaaUeAHZQA1pgD2AMyjEAugC4ZfWVAgAPYBEEATLHSgB+KP0WCIANwgAndgF8eYkFJmyA3O3aSAroNR5xwt6+lDQMABRgVuJgivBIqBjY+ESkkCF09ACUbFC2HkKaVpIAhsjQAJLlgsCSHFyR0QCMiljAVkIA5lScUA1gAEymXgC2cNbd9VFgAMxDo9Z2HkHI5JXVkjSt7YId9GEA5H2N+9kA9KcwaJ4+K2s1m22de4dT-SdQ5wByMMSw-BGvAR6ZygSBQQQjMZWTJAA)